# Category Question

Tags: categories, category-group

Got a bit of a tricky situation, I need to get some categories, that have a product assigned to itself and another category.

Sort of like sub-categories would work but this other category can't be sub-category.

For example,

I've got a category group with the following categories, `Menu 1`, `Menu 2`, `Menu 3`. There is also another category group with the following categories `Drinks`, `Food`.

The second category group is relevant to all the first group categories. So for each `Menu` category, I need to be able to show the `Drinks` or `Food` category as long as there is a product associated with both the category group categories.

Hope that made sense, I can't really think of a way EE could do this. So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There isn't a question in your question here; what are you attempting to do?

Comment: I need to do what I've said above? I can't think of a way EE can do this so I was wondering if anyone else knows a way

Comment: You can assign categories from multiple category groups to an entry; is that what you're asking? Or are you asking how you'd display them in a template, or... ?

Answer (score 1):

If you assign both category groups to your channel (Menu, Food Type) you should be able to use the categories as you want and display which items are part of the menu category regardless of their food or drink classification.

If you'd like more flexibility, however, you might consider making your Menu a channel with entries themselves and using Playa to relate your various food options to them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to attemp but I think I will try to attemp this with Relationship. - Francois

Answer (score 0):

So your "categories " would go...

```
Menu 1
- Drink
- Food
Menu 2
- Drink
- Food
Menu 3
- Drink
- Food
```

You could use categories and sub categories, though you would have to make each subcategory url title unique, eg  menu-1-drink, menu2-drink, menu3-drink.

You could also hard code the Drink/Food links for each Menu x category then use /segment_x values to pull in relevant content.

...and like Jessica suggested use relationships.